Inspect hg mercurial state before pull, after the pull happened
I think I'm missing some commits after pulling this morning, not sure how, but for sure some code changes are now lost. It would be nice to inspect the state of the repository before the pull. Is there any way to do this? Like a local cache?
Edit: In the end, I was looking in the wrong file (confusion caused by code-duplication in the code-base). However, I think the answer is, you cannot restore the state of a hg repository after a hg pull (not the same thing as reverting or undoing a hg pull, which is possible).

Don't know for a fact, but seems unlikely.  Are you saying local commits have disappeared, or that commits should have come in on the pull (and didn't)?

@freefaller Local commits, or at least code changes (don't know exactly to which commit they belong to) are gone after hg pull and a local merge between branches. I'd like to revert the whole repository to its state before hg pull, but it doesn't seem possible.

Unfortunately I would agree... I've been using mercurial (via THG) for over a decade, and although I'm not a power user by any standard, my understanding is that what you see is what you get. I've never seen local commits disappear after a pull

@freefaller Actually, I see now I was looking in the wrong file! :facepalm: Sorry for the trouble. Too much code duplication in this code base... I'll close this question.

Hehe... I know those days. Sounds like time for fika ;-) (Swedish partner)
